# Составной подчинительный союз при пояснительной конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, сложное-предложение

*И только теперь, после того[,] как вы предложили свою помощь и собеседник согласился, обсудите с ним то, чем он может быть полезен вам.*

Самое близкое к нашему случаю условие, при котором составной подчинительный союз расчленяется и запятая ставится между частями союза, следующее: "первая часть составного союза входит в ряд однородных членов предложения или параллельных конструкций» ([Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)).

У нас не однородный член, а **пояснительный**. Ставить запятую между частями союза?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> У нас не однородный член, а пояснительный.

Дело именно в однородных элементах, которые указывают на логическое ударение на первую часть составного союза. Например:
*После первого раза, после второго, после того, как...*

**Не ставить запятую.**

Запятая ставится внутри союза "после того как" и разделяет его, если на первую часть союза падает логическое ударение, есть частицы или усилительные слова. || Этого не наблюдается.
*Я приеду к брату **только** после того, как он позвонит и сам пригласит меня в гости.
Помирюсь с подругой только **лишь** после того, как она первая извинится.*
https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/posle-togo-kak.html

Следующий аргумент.
Придаточное с союзом - в середине основного предложения. Смотрим основу:
*И только теперь, после того обсудите с ним...* || Не годится.
*И только теперь обсудите с ним...* || Нормально - то есть "после того" входит в придаточное.

Но автор имеет право выделить первую часть составного союза, разделив его запятой, - так называемая авторская пунктуация.